# Apply regex on JQ

Tags: regex, bash, jq

I´m using jq to get a json and get some values.

I have this string

```
   "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:foo:task/blablabla"
```

And I want to get the substring from task/ and then return just blablabla

For now I have this regex.

```
 (.*task?)\/(.*$)
```

Which give me two groups.

Any idea how using jq I can apply this regex and get the second group?

Regards

Comment: Are you using unix command line `jq`?

Comment: yes, for now and test it, later on I will move the commands to my bash script

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On jq 1.5, you can pass the regex to `match` and then get the `string` property of `captures`' second element.

```
jq 'match("(.*task?)\/(.*$)").captures[1].string'
```

Comment: Sure. I'm not sure what the `select(.)` in your answer is for, though.

Comment: The `select(.)` is to avoid getting a `null` (or, with `-r`, an empty newline) at the end of the output -- which I did see, in practice, with the exact code quoted in my question without it. As for why my instance of `jq` is seeing more input elements than I intended to feed it, and thus running the match more than once, that's a very good question.

Answer (score 4):

In your BASH script you can take output of `jq` and use BASH string manipulation:

```
s='arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:foo:task/blablabla'
r="${s##*task/}"

# check output
echo "$r"
blablabla
```

`${s##*task/}` will remove longest part upto `task/` from start.

Or you can use `sed`:

```
jq '.selector' | sed 's~.*task/~~'
```

Comment: I was looking for a fancy way to do it in the same line with jq

Comment: Stupid question, is returning me a quote at the end of the string blablabla" how can I get rid of that?. Regards

Comment: When I´m trying xargs jq '.' | sed 's~.*task/~~' | xargs -I {} echo {} is telling me xargs: unterminated quote

Comment: Not working, the thing is that the json is getting from a request. Using this aws ecs list-tasks --cluster bla | xargs jq '.taskArns' | sed -E 's~.*task/|"$~~g'  I´m getting this error

Comment: jq: error: Could not open file {: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file taskArns:: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file [: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:930077579520:task/4eaaa4ef-9ae7-4701-8165-94c4c22f5956: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file ]: No such file or directory
jq: error: Could not open file }: No such file or directory

Comment: Why is `xargs` involved in this at all?

Comment: @anubhava, ...if you added the `-r` argument to `jq` you wouldn't have the quotes to remove, or any other potential JSON formatting escaping of non-literal characters.

Comment: oh thanks that's even better. Then `aws ecs list-tasks --cluster bla | jq -r '.taskArns' | sed 's~.*task/~~'` should work

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use `sub/2`?  For example (in line with the OP's regex):

```
$ jq -r 'sub(".*task/"; "")' <<< '"arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:foo:task/blablabla"'
blablabla
```

It may be better to handle the case where the input string does not contain ":task/", e.g. filtering using `test/1`:

```
select(test(":task/")) | sub( ".*:task/"; "")
```

Consider also using a named-capture group:

```
jq -r 'sub(".*:task/(?<x>.*)"; "\(.x)")' <<< '"arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:foo:task/blablabla"'
blablabla
```

Etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
json_string='"arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:foo:task/blablabla"'
jq 'match("^(.*task?)\/(.*$)", .) | .captures[1].string | select(.)' <<<"$json_string"
```

...emits as output:

```
"blablabla"
```

To emit that as a raw string, without the literal quotes, use the `-r` argument to `jq`.